# Coordinate UV option is missing under Mapping

Tags: texturing, uv, interface

I'm trying to texture a simple plane, but whenever I go to mapping I don't find the UV option that should be there. Here are my steps:

1. Make new object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) then *add mesh* > *plane*
2. Add texture and then open the texture I want to use
   [image: add texture to plane]
3. Go to mapping and then click the coordinate option and there is no UV option.
   [image: Missing the UV option]

Comment: Did you select the material first and then open the texture tab?

Comment: as others answered below, your first image shows you have the "world" selected in the outliner, and the texture panel shows it is in the "world" context (earth icon selected)... the "world" can't be UV mapped (yet) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under what context you are adding your texture into, you can only add UV mapped options to textures added to a material.

You are probably adding a texture to the world or brush context

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So basically for every texture I want to add I need to have a material first then Ill be able to select my texture even if the material is white. Now I know for next time :D